# Integral of total derivative.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am aware of the Leibniz integral rule that let’s you pull in a total derivative into an integral if the limits are constant, and the derivative turns into a partial one.
Additionally, I’m aware that

$$\int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx = f(b) - f(a)$$

is true, under the necessary assumptions. (Note, I only care about the case with constant limits).

My question is, for 
$$ f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
is it possible to use the fundamental theorem of calculus in a situation:
$$\int_a^b \frac{df}{dx}dx$$ 
where the derivative in the integrand is indeed total. 
Or perhaps, to pull the derivative outside of the integral (which I guess then would always be 0). I’ve done a bit of googling, and I cannot find a source that tells me how to deal with situations as such.

Could someone perhaps point to a source that would be helpful in treating situations like the LHS of this equation? Note that here I mean to treat x as one of the ‘axis’ variables, not an independent parameter that can be used to parametrize all variables.

For context, I’m a 3rd year physics undergraduate.

Comment: I think this relates to the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals, where if we treat each component of the gradient as part of a vector field (like a gradient vector field) we can just evaluate the potential function f at its endpoints. Not posting as answer because there is probably more to it than this/ might be wrong. Look at this link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem

Comment: Yes, looking here (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/FundThmLineIntegrals.) It seems like if we assume a parameter for all the variables, we may do something useful. Let me modify my question to include the fact that x is actually one of the R dimensions.